# dynamically change text property of jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have several links:

```
<a href="#" title="Title 1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" title="Title 2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" title="Title 3">Link 3</a>
```

I then have a generic `<div>` to hold contents so that I can reuse it.  It's like this

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is when the user clicks on whatever link, the jQuery dialog opens up with the title of the link (which I have done and will show), but the contents of the dialog will show the text of another div on the page.  So:

```
<div id="someID">Some special content here</div>
```

Here's what I have for the jquery bit:

```
var link = $('#careers > ul > li > a');
link.click(function (e) {
$('#contents').dialog({
    title: e.target.title,
        text: need #specialcontent // <-- THIS IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CHANGE
     });
    return false;
});
```

Is that clear?  I will have other "someID" divs on the page that i would like to switch out based on the click of the link.  So it's essentially loading a new div depending on which is clicked.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does something like this do what you want?

```
var link = $('#careers > ul > li > a');
link.click(function (e) {
    if (link.id == "someID")
        var text_value = "someID's text";
    else if (link.id == "someID2")
        var text_value = "someID2's text";
    $('#contents').dialog({
        title: e.target.title,
        text: text_value #specialcontent // <-- THIS IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CHANGE
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Nakia hmm i don't have your testing environment to try out now, but you could try to see if you can access the link.id in there first by alert(link.id);. if you get it, then you can go on by checking. if not, put the checking outside the function.

Comment: Yes, i can get the ID when I click on a link.

Comment: well, where you can access the id, you can compare it to some string. depending on the result of the comparison you then set some variable text_value to your desired output, and then give it to your element. if it doesnt work with your code above, maybe try
`$('#contents').text(text_value);`?
as a step in between, you can try if you can `alert(text_value);` to narrow down the error range in case something doesn't work.

Comment: The way you're suggesting would mean that under the variable text_value, i'd have to put all of the code that goes there.  I'm trying to load up entire `div` there, which can have any valid HTML elements.  that would make for one really long jscript section when I already have the divs built and ready to go.  Know what i mean?

Comment: of course, instead of `var text_value = "someID2's text";` you can write `var text_value = $("#someDivID').html();`.

Comment: Awesome!  That worked!  At least down the right track.  Had to change it to `$('#someDivD').html(text_value).dialog({});`

I'll just use a switch statment on the link ids so that I can use the same dialog build-out.

Thank you SO MUCH for your help!